# Strange Behaviour of Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

So I am trying to fill a block of memory using `Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned`, unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.
instead of it filling my memory block with the value I specified, it uses an entirely different value. can anyone help out please?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Class1
    {
        internal static unsafe void MemSet(void* dest, byte value, int byteCount)
        {
            Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned(dest, value, (uint) byteCount);
        }

        public static unsafe void Main()
        {
            uint[] kim = new uint[10];
            kim[0] = 213;
            kim[1] = 213;
            kim[2] = 213;
            byte val = 50;

            MemSet((byte*) (uint*) Unsafe.AsPointer(ref kim[0]), val, 3 * Unsafe.SizeOf<uint>());
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", kim));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 values become `842150450`, which is `0x32323232` in hex.
`50` is `0x32` in hex.